# É possível configurar um Rewrite Rule no AWS sem alterar os diretórios?

Tags: amazon-aws, url-amigável, url-rewrite

Estou com um pequeno problema desde que configurei o AWS. O fato é que já veio um pouco preparado quando caiu na minha mão.

Ele está configurado para salvar no dominio.com.br/site/**wordpress**, e ao tentar acessar esse link somente por dominio.com.br acabo caindo no AMI Linux Test Page.

É possível criar um Rewrite Rule para que o dominio.com.br aponte para dentro do wordpress? Mudar os diretórios de lugar agora seria um pouco mais complicado, mas também aceito uma ajuda.

Considere que eu já tentei alguns Rewrites, mas nenhum deles chegou a definitivamente funcionar.

Comment: Cara, acho que o teu problema é só reconfigurar o apontamento do virtual host para o diretório que você quer.
Vc cria ou edita um virtal host para o domínio que você quer, de no documentRoot vc aponta para o diretório desejado.
Eu não sei fazer pelo painel do AWS, acho um pouco poluído o painel, mas sei fazer a configuração no apache. Se for isso que vc precisa avisa aí, que eu posto.

Comment: Diego, é exatamente isso. O Painel do AWS é extremamente confuso e to quebrando a cabeça até agora pra tentar fazer isso funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu suponho que você esteja a usar ubuntu e apache2.4, então possivelmente os teus arquivos de configuração de virtual host sejam armazenados em /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/teudominio.com.br.conf
Edite o teu arquivo .conf com os dados abaixo. Apenas note que o caminho em DocumentRoot e Directory Path devem ser os caminhos correspondentes em teu server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@dominio.com.br
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dominio.com.br/site/wordpress
  ServerName   dominio.com.br
  ServerAlias  www.dominio.com.br
  <Directory /var/www/html/dominio.com.br/site/wordpress>
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Diego, muito obrigado pela resposta, funcionou perfeitamente. Eu até cogitei em mudar pra /var/www/html, mas acho que ficou mais "bonito" com o rewrite.

Comment: Desta forma você pode adicionar mais domínios ao teu servidor. Basta criar novos VirtualHost